# New HP Spectre wont wake from sleep

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep

Ive been working my way through [the HP docs](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03383935) trying to get my brand new laptop to wake when I open the lid, press on the keys, or press the power button, although holding down power does restart it. Ive installed the latest updates, the next thing on the list from HP seems to be turning on keyboard wake. but dont see an option to enable the keyboard. What am I missing? This is what I see in device manager:

[image]

Comment: So, is your problem with the keyboard or is your problem with the computer waking from sleep when you open the lid? Have you considered the laptop does not wake when you open the lid and was not designed to? Many laptops are like that. Sometimes you can change the settings in the BIOS. Other times pressing the power button is required.

Comment: @Appleoddity thanks. Didn't realize how badly I worded that. Post updated, but my issue is I cant get it out of sleep mode at all once I put it to sleep

Comment: Does your BIOS have any options which refer to keyboard / USB waking?

Comment: @VortixDev none that I see

Comment: I notice a Human Interface Devices list just above Keyboards in your image: are there any keyboard devices listed there?

Comment: @VortixDev Nope, just a touch screen